# Spring REST API - How to resolve Ambuiguity in AntPattern matcher

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, matcher

I have a request mapping path that has a pattern and could be in middle or end of the path containing special characters (most likely '/' and '-')

`@RequestMapping("path1/{pattern}")` or `@RequestMapping("path1/{pattern}/remainingPath")`

Possibility 1 - /order/orderId12/5 and need to extract `orderId12/5`

Possibilty 2 -  /order/orderId12/5/details/update/dispatched and need to extract `orderId12/5` only

What I tried so far:

1. Using PathPattern like

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/order/**")
   @RequestMapping("/order/{*orderId}/details/update/{status}")
   ```

But did not work as per [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20In%20contrast%20to%20AntPathMatcher%2C%20**%20is%20supported%20only%20at%20the%20end%20of%20a%20pattern.%20For%20example%20/pages/%7B**%7D%20is%20valid%20but%20/pages/%7B**%7D/details%20is%20not.%20The%20same%20applies%20also%20to%20the%20capturing%20variant%20%7B*spring%7D.%20The%20aim%20is%20to%20eliminate%20ambiguity%20when%20comparing%20patterns%20for%20specificity.)

2. Using AntPatternMatcher

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/order/**")
   @RequestMapping("/order/**/details/update/{status}")
   ```

There is ambiguity here as the second request is falling back to the first request mapping

How do I resolve the ambiguity issue?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you configure the usage of AntPatternMatcher?

Comment: @birca123 By default Spring uses AntPatternMatcher. I forced to use Path Matcher by explicitly specifying in application properties

Comment: Which spring boot version do you use?

Comment: @birca123 I use version 2.5.12

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple way as @PathVariable :

```
@RequestMapping("/order/{id}")
public String getById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
  System.out.println("id is : " + id);
}
```

Comment: Problem is id will have special characters like '/' , '-' which needs to be handled as having '/' in URI